# upload file to postgresql database using react App 2

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, file-upload

this is my code and there is no error but the data don't appear in database

reception.js and service.process.js is frontend and the other is backend

frontend side

1-reception.js

```
  ProcessService.ajouterBon(
        fk_fournisseur,
        acheteur,
        bonScanner,
        type_bon,
        recepteur,
        livreur
      ).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setId_bon(res.data[0].id_bon);
      });
```

2-service.process.js

```
ajouterBon(fk_fournisseur, acheteur,bonScanner, type_bon, recepteur, livreur){


   const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('fk_fournisseur', fk_fournisseur);
    formData.append('acheteur', acheteur); 
    formData.append('scanne_bon', bonScanner);
    formData.append('type_bon', type_bon);
    formData.append('recepteur', recepteur);
    formData.append('livreur', livreur);
   


        //const bon = { fk_fournisseur, acheteur, type_bon, recepteur, livreur }
   return axios.post(PRODUIT_API_BON, formData)
     .then((res) => {
        console.log('data send sucess ');
        console.log(res.data);
        // Handle the response if needed
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error(error);
      });}
```

backend side

1-route.process.js

```
router.post("/ajouterBon", process.ajouterBon);
```

2-controller.process.js

```
ajouterBon = (req, res) => {
  var datee = new Date();
  var heure = HeureNow();
  console.log('data send sucess from controller ');
  var scanne_bon = req.file.path;
  const bon = JSON.parse(req.body.bon);
  const { fk_fournisseur, acheteur, type_bon, recepteur, livreur } = bon;
  pool.query(
    queries.ajouterReception,
    [fk_fournisseur, acheteur,scanne_bon, type_bon, datee, heure, recepteur, livreur],
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.status(200).json(result.rows);
    }
  );
  }
```

3-queries.js

```
const ajouterReception =
  "INSERT INTO bon ( fk_fournisseur, acheteur, scanne_bon, type_bon, datee, heure, recepteur, livreur )
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING id_bon , recepteur , fk_fournisseur";
```